# Animate a DIV element along a SVG path by clicking a button

Tags: html, svg, path, jquery-animate

I have a SVG path:

```
<path d="M124 442 L124 442 L166 393 L162 332 L200 251 L179 76" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" fill="none" fill-opacity="0.1"></path>
```

And I want that a DIV element move along this path when I click a "next-button".

It's like:

```
*startpoint (beginning of the path) + DIV element
*click next-button* + DIV element moves to station 1
*station 1 
*click next-button* + DIV element moves to station 2
*station 2
*click next-button* + DIV element moves to the end of the path
endpoint (end of the path)
```

Does anyone have an idea how I could do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animating a div along svg path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11497494/animating-a-div-along-svg-path)

Answer (score 1):

Found a very helpful tools. Its called path animator.

That could be your friend.

https://github.com/yairEO/pathAnimator

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to animate an HTML element using SVG, then you might want to have a look at [`animateMotion`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateMotionElement) and [`foreignObject`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html#ForeignObjectElement).

However, this might not be the ideal and most widely supported solution in your situation.  Why not use the "traditional" JavaScript way, animating the style attribute? As long as your path is restricted to simple straight line segments, this should not be too hard.